# How to speed up query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

```
var ci = ctx.CI().Where(p => p.PId == pId);

var result = ctx.RM().Where(p => p.R.D.PId == Id && p.MTId == mt.Id).
Sum(p => (((p.M.TN * p.EC * p.F.PW * 52m) + (p.M.TN * p.EC * p.F.PY * (WW / 52m)))
/ 100m) * ci.FirstOrDefault(q => q.PId == p.R.PId.Value && q.FPId == p.R.FPId.Value).Factor);
```

8000 records. Query Takes 2000ms to load doing it this way and 4000 using join on CI and RM.

As you can see there are 6 tables used. CC, RM, R, D, F and M.

Model was defined using CodeFirst, so i'm using EF 4.1.

How can i speed up my query to run way faster than 2 seconds?

Comment: What's the generated TSQL? Did you run the executed TSQL through the plan-based query optimized in SSMS? You could be missing indices.

Answer (score 3):

With a complex query like this, I'm guessing that a lot of the time is being spent compiling the query. Try using `CompiledQuery` to allow you to reuse a precompiled query.

Beyond that, you'll need to analyze the SQL that gets produced to see where time is spent in the execution plan. It's possible that you'll be able to significantly improve performance with a few well-placed indices.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stored procedure, and bind the ef to a function for it.